# JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Tags: linux, linux-mint, java, maven

If anyone can help me with this, it would mean a lot as I've seen similarly answered questions for windows but not many or Linux. I am running I am running Linux mint 20.2 (Uma).

I have a problem where trying to run my maven project, I get the error

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

I have since fully uninstalled java and maven and set up JDK17 and the JAVA_HOME

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.2
```

Along with setting the profile

```
$ grep JAVA_HOME /etc/profile

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.2
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
```

And .bashrc

```
$ grep JAVA_HOME ~/.bashrc

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.2
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
```

I also found a `maven.sh` file in the `/etc/profile.d/` that was redirecting JAVA_HOME to the old JDK and have since deleted it.

But even after all of this the problem pressies, I don't know if something is still redirecting JAVA_HOME to the old JDK or I didn't set it up correctly, I also don't know where to look if something is redirecting it or if I have an alias for `mvn` since I'm not adept to Linux fully and I haven't used to this system in a while to backtrack my changes.

If anyone has any input on how to solve this problem, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Did you follow these steps : https://linuxhint.com/install_java_linux_mint/ ?

Comment: Not this one exactly, but it correctly installed as ```java --version 
java 17.0.2 2022-01-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86, mixed mode, sharing)``` gives the correct output

Comment: Have you sourced the init files or stared a new shell session after making the changes to the init files?

Comment: yes I have even my IDE recognizes the new JDK when trying to run maven ```cd /home/brainlet/NetBeansProjects/eding_priject; JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.2 /tmp/.mount_NetBeaWQErAL/netbeans/java/maven/bin/mvn install```

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue may be the path variable: You include both JRE and JDK bin. I suggest you change it to `PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin`, keeping JDK binaries reachable only. That's my setup and I haven't had any issues.

If this doesn't help, I'd suggest you to download [OpenJDK](https://jdk.java.net/17/), untar it and change the path to the downloaded OpenJDK directory.